# Use of the mth - convergence test and its advantages

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I've just learned about the mth-convergence test (I listed it below) and can't seem to imagine when would it be useful, and what are some of its consequences.

This one is specifically for m = 2:

Let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ be a positive-term series. Let
$$ L = \max{\{\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}}, \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_n}}\}} $$
and
$$ l = \min{\{\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}}, \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_n}}\}} $$

- If $L < \frac{1}{2}$, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ converges.
- If $l > \frac{1}{2}$, then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ diverges.
- If $l \leq \frac{1}{2} \leq L $, then the test is inconclusive.

And also the m-version:

Let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ be a positive-term series and let $m > 1$ be a fixed positive integer. Let
$$ L_1 = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn}}{a_n}},\: L_2 = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn+1}}{a_n}}, \: \ldots \:, \: L_m = \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn + m - 1}}{a_n}},$$
$$ l_1 = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn}}{a_n}},\: l_2 = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn+1}}{a_n}}, \: \ldots \:, \: l_m = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{a_{mn + m - 1}}{a_n}}.$$
Let
$$ L = \max{\{L_1, L_2, \ldots , L_m\}} \quad \text{and} \quad l = \min{\{l_1, l_2, \ldots , l_m\}}. $$

- If $L < \frac{1}{m}$,then $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ converges.
- If $l > \frac{1}{m}$, then$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} $ diverges.
- If $ l \leq \frac{1}{m} \leq L $ , then the test is inconclusive.